# How do I add a class to the first element in PHP on WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I've created a custom post type that utilizes Twitter Bootstraps carousel. I did some modification and can't seem to add the class 'active' to the first element.

The place I'm trying to modify is on line 53
[Pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/4UZt80cG)

EDIT: So I'm following this [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-filterable-portfolio-with-wordpress-and-jquery/?search_index=6) to create my custom post type and I'm creating a homepage rotator using Twitter Bootstraps carousel. So far I'm able to bring in the image, title, and excerpt. Also the rotator is functioning as I click left or right on the navigation of the carousel, only thing though I can't seem to add the class 'active' to the very first element or new post I should say. I've looked around, tried for loop(my PHP skills is not well) and my for loop didn't seem to work. I've also tried using the counter in the for loop that didn't fly either. My logic may be off if someone can guide towards the right direction I gladly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: [**paste your code here, see the Stackoverflow Tour to see how**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and keep in mind that questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [**Stack Overflow question checklist**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: I’d just do it with JavaScript; the carousel is JS-powered anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple potential issues here.

I am guessing you might have an operator precedence issue.  In your code here:

```
if(!$count % 1) echo 'active';
```

The `!` will be processed before the `%` operator.  Thus is you have a non-zero value in `$count`, you will in essence be doing this:

```
if(false % 1) echo 'active';
```

Which I am guessing is not what you want.

Use parenthesis to get you operation order correct:

```
if(!($count % 1)) echo 'active';
```

That being said, you also seem to have a logical issue with how you are using the modulus operator. A modulus of `1` is probably not going to do anything for you here, as if (as I assume) `$count` is an integer value, there will never be a remainder when dividing by one, thus your conditional will always be:

```
if(!0) echo 'active';
```

Which, of course, will always evaluate as true, which defeats the point of having a conditional in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the poor layout of your code...

The `if` statement you're talking about is never going to evaluate to `TRUE` and so the class won't be added.

`!$count % 1` essentially converts `$count` to either `TRUE` or `FALSE` and then performs the `% 1` operation...

Logic dictates that `(int > 0) == TRUE`. So your code, would evaluate to `TRUE` on the first loop (where `$count == 0`) if you left off the `% 1`.

However, since you have the `% 1` (outputs the remainder of a divide operation) it evaluates to false. This is because the `TRUE` (the value of `!$count` when `$count == 0`) is equal to `1` (i.e. `bool(TRUE) == int(1)`) and `1 % 1 == 0` and therefore `FALSE`.

You could either leave off `% 1` or use `% 2` (or any number greater than `1`).

Furthermore, you don't appear to increment your counter anywhere in your code... You need to increment it at the end of every loop by using something like `$count++` or `$count += 1` OR at least you need to increment it as part of your `IF` statement so that it doesn't apply to every subsequent loop like:

```
if(!$count){
    echo "...";
    $count++;
}
```

Comment: Yeah man that's my bad, I'm still learning PHP. I'll give this a shot. Thanks!